# How to determine default algorithm mcrypt uses

Tags: encryption, defaults

[`mcrypt`](http://mcrypt.sourceforge.net/) selects a default from one of its possible encryption algorithms if one isn't explicitly named.  `mcrypt --list` shows all available algorithms, but doesn't mark which one is default.  Neither encrypting nor decrypting a file output which algorithm is being used.  So, how do I figure out the default?

Answer (score 3):

The latest versions of [`file`](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) will tell you the algorithm used on a file encrypted by `mcrypt`:

```
$ mcrypt foo.bar

$ file foo.bar.nc

foo.bar.nc: mcrypt 2.5 encrypted data, algorithm: rijndael-128, keysize: 32 bytes, mode: cbc,
```